# How do I get ALLOWED_HOSTS working with debug false?

Tags: django

I am totally stumped why I can't get my site to work when `DEBUG=False`.

I have entered my domain name and IP address in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

I even tried putting '*' in my `ALLOWED_HOST` but when `DEBUG=False` I
always get my 400.html page served to me. As soon as `DEBUG=True`
everything works great.

I have search through google tried all the checks people say to try (
I think) , all my urls end in '/'. none of my `local.py` or `base.py` have
`DEBUG` setting or `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['1.2.3.4', 'www.myhost.com', '*' , ]
```

Nothing seems to be working.

I even inserted by own dummy `LoginRequierdMiddleware` class it does get
called but I don't see anything wrong with request coming in.

```
class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
      def process_request(self, request):
            print request
```

I am running nginx and apache2 in production environment. I am really
stuck , desperately need help!Any clues on how to debug this?

---

Answering my own question: in case someone make same mistake as I did

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/base.py",
line 121, in get_filename
    filename = self.storage.path(basename)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
line 261, in path
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
SuspiciousFileOperation: Attempted access to '/css/bootstrap311.min.css' denied.
Not Found: /accounts/login/

the way I debugged this was creating following setup in my
production.py and then /tmp/debug.log had this error.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I removed the {% compress %} tags from my templates for now so I can
disable DEBUG on my "production/demo" server and everything works
great now!

Comment: Maybe stupid question - after changes to settings.py did you reload we server?

Comment: I did upload my server. I re-edited my question with what was reason I was getting this error. In case someone runs into same issue also general process of how to debug this specific issue.